# Printf not aligned when more than one extra digit is added

Tags: c, printf, padding

I'm trying to align multiple variables in a table like output.
I am currently using padding but I can not see how to correctly align the output.
I print the variables:

```
printf("\n %15s", name);
printf("%15d", level);
```

Then I call the next function repeatedly, all is fine unless there is more than one digit.

```
printf("%11dhr  %.1fmn",t,t2);
```

[image]

Comment: @nnn is this to go into the printf function that prints t and t2/

Comment: @nnn thank you, could you please post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the variables defined as `int t;` and `float t2;` (or `double t2;`), as it is now `%.1f` prints `t2` with *one* digit after the decimal point. This is the *precision specifier*.

For alignment, you want also to include the *width specifier* (minimum number of characters to be printed, padded with spaces if less are available). This should include the decimal point and the precision digits. So if the integer part of `t2` will fit when printed in 2 characters, you will need to set the width to 4. For the given example, this should work:

```
printf("%11dhr  %4.1fmn", t, t2);
```